# Regular expression to enforce at least one space between values of full name

Tags: regex

I want to verify that a user provides at least two parts for a full name (first and last names - for example: John Smith)

It has to be a regular expression because I want to use it for both server and client side validation.

```
public const string NameFull = @"^[a-zA-Z\.\'\-\s]{2,50}$";
```

**How can I make it so at least one space will be required and at least two values in each side?**

For example (match): "First Last", "Given Middle Family"

For example (not match): "Firstnameonly"

**UPDATE**:
And the winner is:

```
public const string NameFull = @"^(?!.{52,})[a-zA-Z\.\'\-]{2,50}(?: [a-zA-Z\.\'\-]{2,50})+$";
```

Comment: How about `\w+\s+\w+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z\.\'\-]{2,50}(?: [a-zA-Z\.\'\-]{2,50})+$
```

You can this to ensure `space` separated words.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/28

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much! by the way, how can also enforce {5,51} on the whole expression instead of {2,50} on each word?

Comment: This fails on a middle initial only. Or an initial for any of the word parts.

Comment: @evolross can you post some examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
public const string NameFull = @"^[a-zA-Z.'-]+(?: +[a-zA-Z.'-]+)+$";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC3rT8/5)